# Unable to query the 'permissions' FQL table with the app access_token instead of the user access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to query the `permissions` FQL table with my app `access_token` with something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?&access_token=337313372909587|U_TaFVlx-9D6vOJXXXXZp22034k&q=select user_about_me from permissions where uid = me()
```

Where `337313372909587|U_TaFVlx-9D6vOJXXXXZp22034k` is my app access token (of course I changed it)

The problem is that it doesn't work. If I try, instead, to replace the app `access_token` with the `user access_token`, it works.

The point is that, according to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/) what I'm trying to do should be possible.

Is this a bug, either in the API or in the documentation? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's not a typo in your question, you are using `where uid=me()` in the query

`me()` is a placeholder for the user ID of the current session user (i.e the user whose access token you're using)

If you're trying to make that call with an app access token you need to specify the user ID

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&q=select user_about_me from permissions where uid =  USER_ID` should work (works for me)

Comment: That was the problem, really thank you. I thought to have tried it, but seems that in the many attempts I eventually didn't.